# WCF Security using NetTCPBinding with TcpClientCredentialType.Windows

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, service

I'm new to `WCF` and I have a relatively simple question that I can't seem to find a simple answer for. I am trying to see if I have to explicitly use certificates to verify both ends of the binding are genuine. I would prefer to use the `TcpClientCredentialType.Windows` security to do it all for me with `ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign`. Is this sufficient for both client and server to trust each other that they haven't been tampered with? Both my client dll and the server processes are signed with the same certificate but could somebody just create a fake service that uses my contract and my client would not realise?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN contains a list of the best practices to consider when creating secure applications using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

WCF offers two mechanisms for peer-to-peer authentication: X509 certificates (used by peer channel) and Windows authentication where an SSPI negotiation downgrades from Kerberos to NTLM.  Certificate-based authentication using key sizes of 1024 bits or more is preferred to NTLM for several reasons:

- the availability of mutual authentication,
- the use of stronger cryptographic algorithms, and
- the greater difficulty of utilizing forwarded X509 credentials.

For what it's worth, you may want to consider certificates, even self-signed certificates, to ensure optimum endpoint security.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and excuse me for my ignorance but are you saying that the Windows authentication is sufficient (providing the service process is signed with the same cert) for my client to be satisfied that the WCF service it is connecting to is the real one it is expecting and not a fake one?

Comment: Bad typo lol, that should read 'insufficient' which of course completely inverts the meaning. 

So for the validation I seek to ensure both ends are the real ones you are saying I MUST use certificates?

Comment: I don't think you "MUST" use certificates, but rather that certificates IMHO (and according to MSDN) represent the best practice to secure web services and verify the endpoint identity

Comment: Well my issue is I will be installing the WCF service and clients on customer machines but I want to prevent the customer from replacing my genuine service with their own. It seems I have to provide a certificate protected setup but that means issuing certificates with private keys. This is something I thought was not the done thing so I'm struggling to see how I can achieve my validation of the client/server authenticity without compromising security. Am I missing something?

Comment: In a public key infrastructure (PKI), the private keys should NOT be exchanged.  Rather, the digital certificate, which contains just the public key, is exchanged.

Comment: Well I was hopeful but when I tried to re-use my digital signing cert for WCF it complained there was no private key to use for exchange. Now I have read somewhere that this sort of cert is not the same as one used for messaging but I don't like the idea of putting down certs with private keys on users machines. I just want a way of knowing when my client hits the WCF service on the 'server' that it's not some fake service pretending to be mine.

Comment: You may decide to take another approach, but the following article provides a good overview of setting up certificates with WCF.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx